# SSH using Putty and Xming: how to reconnect to display after logout?

Tags: ssh, putty, xming

I am using Putty and Xming to SSH to a remote linux machine. I use `screen` so that I can keep things running in the background after I logout or a dropped connection.

However, when I reattach back to the screen subsequently, the display window of Xming is not shown. How can I get the display to show? Are there methods more suitable for my needs?

Comment: Maybe this belongs to superuser as it is not a programming issue.